# SharePoint group is treated as one user or multiple users when sending mail?

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-designer, workflow, groups, exchange-server

I got request to make possible of sending template mail from SPD2013 workflow to more than 50 users at once. List of people will vary, so we cannot create ad distribution group, but I thought of SharePoint group.

Will SP group be treated as one user and mail will be sent smoothly or will workflow break and won't send emails?

Beside this, if you have any other idea how to manage sending template mail from SPD to multiple users is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I think SharePoint group would be better.Because it will easily manage to add or remove user from SharePoint group.

If you are use SharePoint group then it will send mail to all users who are in that group and in mail to address all users email address who are in that group.

I don't think it will create any problem for sending mail.

Use send email activity in SPD workflow and choose SharePoint group or distribution list in to.